# В symfony не получается сделать if is_page(current_page) проверку по странице (

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
app.request.get('_route')


{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'road-construction' %}
    <a href="{{ path('road-construction') }}" class="YouAreHere">My Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Не работает(
Это [динамическая страница](https://bi-group.org/ru/company/road-construction) и у них общий шаблон(
У страниц таких общий шаблон индекс но через админку была создана страница динамическая и так как можно разделить динамические ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if '/company/road-construction' in app.request.uri  %}
                    <a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">Open modal</a>

                        <div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
                            <h1>Modal dialog</h1>

                            <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Закрыть</a></p>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
```